# How to turn on OpenMP when using Qt creator

Tags: openmp

If I am building the project from Qt creator using VS 2010 compiler, how do i enable OpenMP (when building from visual studio you just enable the feature) Thanks

Comment: I tried CONFIG+=/openmp    but that didnt work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try next in your .pro file

in case msvc2010

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -openmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -openmp
```

or

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -fopenmp
```

in case gcc

Comment: MSVC's linker does not need or accept `-openmp` so you should not set `QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -openmp`.